# Why does my NSDate (only time part) string format not able to convert to long?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

Am taking input from UIDatePicker and my output is in this format 
**`3:24:00 AM`**  but when i tried to convert this back to NSDate and from there long its returning a null value.

My code:

```
    NSDate* sourceDate = self.timePicker.date;

    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:sourceDate
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoneStyle
                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);   //3:25:00 AM  string value
```

Converting dateString to NSDate

```
    NSDate *dateVal=(NSDate *)dateString;
    NSLog(@"%@", dateVal); // printing null in console
```

converting  dateVal  to long

```
    long val=[d timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
    NSLog(@"%ld",val); // printing 0
```

How do i solve this issue? please help me

Iam expecting a long value for time part of NSDate

Comment: Because your `d` value is nil.

Comment: **Converting dateString to NSDate** : You can not convert directly NSString to NSDate You need to use DateFormatter. What you expect at **Converting dateString to NSDate**?

Comment: Well, if it weren't nil (for a reason that's not shown in your above code) then you'd get "unrecognized selector", because `timeIntervalSince1970` is not a method of NSString.

Comment: so do you know any solution for this?

Comment: Correct the code.  For starters you can show us the *real* code.

Comment: NSDate stores the time in UTC.  What time zone is the device set for?

Comment: Why are you converting date to string, then back to date again? Just use sourceDate.

Comment: am getting a nsdate with time part but i need only long value of that time part (i don't want long value of date time)

Comment: `NSDate *dateVal=(NSDate *)dateString;` Casting is not converting. all it does is to tell the compile to shut up.

Comment: so what you are suggesting me to do?

Comment: these question was answered literally thousands of times. search for it.

Comment: You need to spend some time learning about NSDate.  Start by reading the specs for NSDate, NSCalendar, NSDateFormatter, and NSDateComponents.

Comment: if you can find the same question then i will give 1000 bucks here..same question i meant it...@ vikingosegundo  and if you don't know anything don't open your mouth

Comment: You have a very poor attitude.  You ask for people to help you, and when they give you valid advice you criticize them.  This sort of question about date conversion appears here with appalling regularity, and in virtually all cases it reveals that the person asking the question simply does not understand how NSDate works, and, in many cases, has made no effort to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

// Convert string to date object

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

This will help you to Convert dateString to NSDate

Comment: Again, search this site. There are hundreds before you who believed they got the wrong output because they didn't understand NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following :

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
[df setDateFormat:@"h:m:s a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

You need to convert a string to an NSDate object. A simple way to do this is using the NSDateFormatter object. It provides the dateFromString method which converts a string into an NSDate object. You do, however, need to tell NSDateFormatter the format the date will be in.

Date formatter reference :

```
 a           AM/PM
 A           millisecond of day
 c           day of week (c,cc,ccc,cccc)
 d           day of month
 e           day of week (e,EEE,EEEE)
 F           week of month
 g           julian day (since 1/1/4713 BC)
 G           era designator (G=GGG,GGGG)
 h           hour (1-12, zero padded)
 H           hour (0-23, zero padded)
 L           month of year (L,LL,LLL,LLLL)
 m           minute of hour (0-59, zero padded)
 M           month of year (M,MM,MMM,MMMM)
 Q           quarter of year (Q,QQ,QQQ,QQQQ)
 s           seconds of minute (0-59, zero padded)
 S           fraction of second
 u           zero padded year
 v           general timezone (v=vvv,vvvv)
 w           week of year (0-53, zero padded)
 y           year (y,yy,yyyy)
 z           specific timezone (z=zzz,zzzz)
 Z           timezone offset +0000

 sql         y-M-d H:m:s
 rss         [E, ]d MMM y[y] H:m:s Z|z[zzz]
```

Comment: i have tried but getting wrong output date . let me try once more

Comment: What output did you get ?

Comment: Because the exact string you get from `[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:sourceDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];` is not `3:25:00 AM`

Comment: now working...when i select 06:39 am getting  this 2000-01-01 06:39:51

Comment: Yes but I guess the Data is not correct because of `2000-01-01`

Comment: am selecting 6:51:00 pm
 but jam getting  2000-01-01 07:21:00 +0000   time part is wrong why??

Comment: 30 minutes difference in time

Comment: `[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];`

Comment: still 30 minutes  ahead

Comment: `[df setDateFormat:@"M/DD/YY, h:m:s a"];`

Comment: Because the format is not good, so make some test with Formatter reference I gave you in my answer. But it's the way you have to do it.